# Splitting string by spaces but ignore spaces inside a quote

Tags: c#, regex, csv, split

I have a big string which has got data from a csv file, however when using regular expressions such as:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w+|""[\w\s]*""");
```

it splits every letter instead? there are no spaces foreach line, only at the end of the line - but shouldn't be cutting the line where there is a space inside double quotes.

> example: test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,"test 6",test7 (new
>   line)test8,test9,etc.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction? thanks

Comment: Can you use an existing library, such as: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend referring to [an existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441556/parsing-csv-input-with-a-regex-in-java) than reinventing your own (unless you're going for the learning experience!)  Parsing CSV is trickier than it seems.

**EDIT:** Didn't see you were using C#.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268622/regex-to-split-line-csv-file) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833088/csv-regular-expression).

Comment: The main trickiness with parsing CSV is figuring out what the exact rules are. There are so many different variants, with slight differences. Actually parsing it once you figured out which rules you need isn't that hard, even when you do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing CSV parser instead of trying to use `Regex` - the format is subtle, as you have seen.

[FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is one popular library for this and there is the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) living in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace.

Comment: I can't imagine this being the best way to do this, but right now its my only option. Thanks

Comment: @MarkW - Best? In terms of what? Dev effort? Maintainability? Speed? Correct results?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but here is a regex that worked for me.

```
string SplitRegex = @"(?:,)|(['""][^""]*['""])(?:,)*";
    
string input = "\"dear friend, I'm home\", \"Thanks, your other friend.\"";


var results = Regex.Split(input, SplitRegex)
                                .Select(x => x.Trim())
                                .Where(match => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
                                .ToList();
    
foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Outputs:

```
"dear friend, I'm home"
"Thanks, your other friend."
```